# Flex mobile app to record and playback voice on Ipad 2

Tags: ios, mobile, audio, flex4.5, voice

I was wondering if anyone here had any experience with developing a Flex application for IOS that records voice and plays it on Ipad 2 ?

If any one has any idea about how to do this please give me a hint.
I am already developing and running flex apps on Ipad but i have no idea how to record voice through my app.

Comment: Just in case anyone still interested in this topic, they can find solutions for all points mentioned above on the latest version of Tour de Flex (Web version)